# Why is boost::hana's set not default constructable?

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, template-meta-programming, boost-hana

today I found that `boost::hana`'s `map` and `set` aren't default constructable, while the `tuple` is. Is there any particular reason for this because it is quite annoying.

This

```
#include <boost/hana/set.hpp> 
//                   ^^^ or map

constexpr boost::hana::set<> a{};
//                     ^^^ or map

int main(){}
```

fails with the following error:

```
main.cpp:3:30: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'const boost::hana::set<>'
constexpr boost::hana::set<> a{};
                             ^~~
/home/russellg/Documents/boost/hana-0.6.0/include/boost/hana/set.hpp:65:28: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument 'xs', but no arguments were provided
        explicit constexpr set(tuple<Xs...> const& xs)
                           ^
/home/russellg/Documents/boost/hana-0.6.0/include/boost/hana/set.hpp:69:28: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument 'xs', but no arguments were provided
        explicit constexpr set(tuple<Xs...>&& xs)
                           ^
/home/russellg/Documents/boost/hana-0.6.0/include/boost/hana/set.hpp:57:12: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were
      provided
    struct set
           ^
/home/russellg/Documents/boost/hana-0.6.0/include/boost/hana/set.hpp:57:12: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were
      provided
1 error generated.
```

even though it is perfectly valid to have an empty map or set:

```
#include <boost/hana/set.hpp>
//                   ^^^ or map

constexpr auto a = boost::hana::make_set();
//                                   ^^^ or map

int main(){}
```

Which compiles flawlessly.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

It doesn't actually matter if it is empty, it is *always* illegal to default construct `map`s and `set`s.

Comment: Do you need any more clarification or rationale about this issue? If not, it would be nice to accept the provided answer, which seems correct to me.

Comment: No thank you for reminding me :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hana::set` and `hana::map` representations are implementation-defined.  The documentation warns against their direct usage and mentions that the canonical way to create these is via `hana::make_set` and `hana::make_map` respectively.  The [documentation](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/structboost_1_1hana_1_1set.html) states:

> The actual representation of a `hana::set` is implementation-defined. In particular, one should not take for granted the order of the template parameters and the presence of any constructor or assignment operator. The canonical way of creating a `hana::set` is through `hana::make_set`.

`hana::tuple` is a simpler container, documents its representation, and strives to maintain some parity with `std::tuple`.  The `hana::basic_tuple` [documentation](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/structboost_1_1hana_1_1basic__tuple.html) notes:

> [...] `hana::tuple` aims to provide an interface somewhat close to a `std::tuple` [...]

---

As to why `hana::set` and `hana::map`'s representations are implementation-defined, consider reading the [FAQ](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/index.html#tutorial-rationales-container_representation), but in short:

- allows more flexibility to implement compile-time and runtime optimizations
- knowing the type is usually not very useful

---

There is a github [issue](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/issues/197) to consider adding a default-constructor for `hana::map`.

Comment: Alright. How would you suggest passing a container in a template argument for a class?

Comment: @RussellGreene Via a templated factory function for the class.

Comment: Alright, but what would the value of the template arguments be?

Comment: BTW: decltype(boost::hana::make_set()) a{}; fails too... What is wrong with that?

Comment: @RussellGreene The value of the template argument would be the result of `make_X()` or Boost.Hana algorithms.  Your latter code assumes the presence of a default constructor, for which the documentation makes no guarantee and warns against assuming the presence of any constructor.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Although to be correct, the documentation should guarantee the presence of copy and move constructors whenever the elements inside the `hana::set` support it. [I'll fix this](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/issues/217).

Out of curiosity, why do you want to store a `hana::set` as a class member? Since the elements of a `hana::set` are required to be compile-time `Comparable`, these elements are most likely singleton types without an actual runtime value. Why do you need to store this as a class member?

Comment: You're probably right. I was porting a library from boost mpl as an exercise in hana, and was replacing typedefs with static constexpr variables. Should I just stick with a typedef, then construct when needed? Or... What?

Comment: There's no algorithm for automatically porting MPL code to Hana. Without seeing some code, it's really hard to give any advice.